# Python - urllib3 ClosedPoolError on crawling

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, python-multithreading, urllib3

I am building a crawler with `python3` and `urllib3`. I am using a `PoolManager` instance that is used by 15 different threads. While crawling thousands of website i get a lot of `ClosedPoolError` from different website.

On the documentation - `ClosedPoolError`:

> Raised when a request enters a pool after the pool has been closed.

It appears that the `PoolManager` instance is trying to use a closed connection.

My code:

```
from urllib3 import PoolManager, util, Retry
from urllib3.exceptions import MaxRetryError

# Instance of PoolManager is started on init
manager = PoolManager(num_pools=15,
                      maxsize=6,
                      timeout=40.0,
                      retries=Retry(connect=2, read=2, redirect=10))

# Every thread execute download by using the pool manager instance
url_to_download = "**"
headers = util.make_headers(accept_encoding='gzip, deflate',
                            keep_alive=True,
                            user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0")
headers['Accept-Language'] = "en-US,en;q=0.5"
headers['Accept'] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
try:
   response = manager.request('GET',
                                   url_to_download,
                                   preload_content=False,
                                   headers=headers)
except MaxRetryError as ex:
   raise FailedToDownload()
```

How can i make the `PoolManager` renew the connection and try again?

Comment: Sounds like a bug somewhere. Are you doing anything weird with the internals of the manager? Which version of urllib3 are you using? Try using the latest version just in case. If that doesn't help, please open an issue. :)

Comment: I've updated to the latest version and still the same behavior, wiil open an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem I ended up patching _get_conn to unblock myself but this is far from an ideal solution:

```
def _get_conn(self, timeout=None):
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = self.pool.get(block=self.block, timeout=timeout)

    except AttributeError:  # self.pool is None
        return self._new_conn()

    except queue.Empty:
        if self.block:
            raise EmptyPoolError(
                self, "Pool reached maximum size and no more connections are allowed.",
            )
        pass

    if conn and is_connection_dropped(conn):
        log.debug("Resetting dropped connection: %s", self.host)
        conn.close()
        if getattr(conn, "auto_open", 1) == 0:
            conn = None

    return conn or self._new_conn()


connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool._get_conn = _get_conn
```